# Aggregate count query is not working anymore in Meteor 1.8

Tags: meteor

I have been using Aggregate in queries for getting total records count, but today I migrated from Meteor 1.2 to 1.8, and now this following query is giving me an exception:

**I am using meteorhacks:aggregate @ version 1.3.0 on server-side**

**Query:**

```
Articles.aggregate([
      { $match: {userId: 'a767GGhrd743Ghe349sd'} },
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }               
])[0];
```

**Exception:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property \'count\' of undefined\n
```

In Meteor 1.2 same query was giving me the counter but as I have updated to Meteor 1.8, now it is not working anymore.

Comment: Do you apply the aggregate by using an atmosphere package or by the mongo driver default built-in in Meteor? Is this on server or minimongo client?

Comment: Using atmosphere package, and its on server side

Comment: Please add the package name and package version so it can be ensured that there is no issue with package compatibility and Meteor 1.8

Comment: I have updated my question with package and and version

Comment: does my answer below solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package you are using (`meteorhacks:aggregate`) is abandoned since about 2015. With the new Mongo >= 3.0.0 (which has been introduced since Meteor 1.7) this package will not work anymore as there are breaking changes in the Mongo driver.

The alternative would be either to self-implement the aggregate functionality against [the latest Mongo driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) or to use an active maintained fork of the package like [`sakulstra:aggregate`](https://github.com/sakulstra/meteor-aggregate).

The forked package itself [described the problem as well](https://github.com/sakulstra/meteor-aggregate#what-the-fork):

> meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate seems pretty unmaintained, so let's maintain a fork! Meteor 1.7 and it's upgrade to mongodriver v3 introduced some breaking changes which will break meteorhacks:meteor-aggregate.